# Jenkins somehow creates ws-cleanup_timestamp file

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job, that triggers a script. Everything is ok, but in the foulder, where a script is placed, it creates a file with name

```
JOBNAME_ws-cleanup_TIMESTAMP
```

JOBNAME AND TIMESTAMP are variables from a Jenkins job.

Why does it happen. Why does Jenkins create a file?

Comment: are you using jenkins slaves ? is it relevant to you? https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24824

Comment: Yeah, I am using jenkins slaves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should use **latest** Jenkins workspace cleanup plugin
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ws-cleanup/

Comment: why did you ask about slaves? I guess, that the problem can be there, but where exactly.

Comment: there was a bug on cleaning work space on slaves which was fixed https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-24824

Answer (score 2):

This bug still persists in 2020. As a walk around we did manual deletion with crontab. This is a very dirty way, but it works and stabilizes the CPU consumption of Jenkins. Please take your own responsibility enabling this command.

*crontab -e*

```
1 1 1 1-12 * cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ && find . -type d -name "*_ws-cleanup_*" -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Crontab explanation:

*“At 01:01 on day-of-month 1 in every month from January through December.”*